# Get user input from TextField from one FXML file to another

Tags: java, javafx

There are few other threads with similar problem, but I tried implementing codes given in those answers but so far I have no success. I'll provide notable parts of my code. I have two FXML files `LoginFXML` and `DockFXML` and one `TextField tfUsername`. I want to pass input that user enters in `tfUsername` as a `String`  from `LoginFXML` to `DockFXML`.

I'll remove unnecessary code in examples below.

**LoginFXMLController**

```
public class LoginFXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField tfUsername;

    private void animateWhenLoginSuccess(){
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("DockFXML.fxml"));
            Parent main = fxmlLoader.load();
            DockFXMLController c = (DockFXMLController) fxmlLoader.getController();
            c.loginUsername = tfUsername.getText();
//        Print below works which means that a String is okay
            System.out.println(c.loginUsername);
    }

    @FXML
    private boolean loginSuccessful() throws SQLException{

//        Login check in MySQL
    }
}
```

**DockFXMLController**

```
public class DockFXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblName;

    public String loginUsername;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        lblName.setText(loginUsername);
    }    
}
```

So the output that I'd like to get in this example is to show what user entered in `LoginFXML` and show it on a `Label lblName` in `DockFXML`.

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize()` method is called as part of the process of loading the fxml file. This means the line

```
lblName.setText(loginUsername);
```

in `DockFXMLController` is executed before the line

```
c.loginUsername = tfUsername.getText();
```

in `LoginFXMLController`.

You need to use a set method, so that you can update the label when you set the `loginUserName`:

```
public class DockFXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblName;

    private String loginUsername;

    public String getLoginUserName() {
        return loginUserName ;
    }

    public void setLoginUserName(String userName) {
        loginUserName = userName ;
        lblName.setText(loginUsername);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    
}
```

and then you do

```
private void animateWhenLoginSuccess(){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("DockFXML.fxml"));
        Parent main = fxmlLoader.load();
        DockFXMLController c = (DockFXMLController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        c.setLoginUsername(tfUsername.getText());
}
```

Note that the actual variable `loginUsername` is now pretty much redundant: you can just do

```
public class DockFXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblName;

    public String getLoginUserName() {
        return lblName.getText() ;
    }

    public void setLoginUserName(String userName) {
        lblName.setText(userName);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    
}
```

and you can even expose the full property (which would allow you register listeners and create bindings, if you need) by adding the method

```
    public StringProperty loginUserNameProperty() {
        return lblName.textProperty();
    }
```

(neither of these would change the `LoginController` code above).

Comment: Thanks for that. I completely overlooked the fact `that initialize()` method is being called before. I was reading about `Properties` and it looks like it could be much better way to access `loginUsername` and to call it multiple times without having to edit `animateWhenLoginSuccess()` each time. Is it possible to use it here?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "edit `animateWhenLoginSuccess()` each time". I updated with some slightly better options (including exposing a property from the second controller), but don't really know what you're asking there.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. By "edit `animateWhenLoginSuccess()` each time" I meant that when I want to lets say display some image that is in a database and I have to find it by username, I would have to ` c.setProfileImage(tfUsername.getText());` for example. Not sure if my logic there is good or not, but so far (with your help) I can display first and last name from a database using username.